# notification add my own sound

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm adding a notificationCompat to my app, it works fine, but now I would like to add my own sound to the notification, so, I read that is:

```
.setSound(Uri sound);
```

But, I cant get the uri, how should I do this? where should the .wav file in my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add your own notiffication sound follow this step. edit in your service class.

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),0, myIntent,Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                // myNotification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
                 myNotification.sound = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.adroid.alarm"+R.raw.airtel_latest);
```

Put sound file in raw folder. Edit com.adroid.alarm with your package name.

Comment: just a comment, a "/" is missed after alarm